# Golang HTTP Concurrent Requests POST EOF

Tags: http, web, go

I'm running a small client in Go. We're getting a number of false alarms at the moment, which seem to come down to `client.Do()` returning an EOF error when `num>=1000`.

This is the essence of my code:

```
func DoCreate(js string, cli *http.Client) {

    url2 := "http://xvz.myserver.com:9000/path/create"

    postBytesReader := bytes.NewReader([]byte(js))
    request, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", url2, postBytesReader)

    resp, err := cli.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err) // Post http://xvz.myserver.com:9000/path/create: EOF 
        return
    }
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Println(string(body))

    defer resp.Body.Close()
}

func main() {
    client := &http.Client{
        CheckRedirect: nil,
    }

    for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
        var pq CreateReqInfo
        pq.Uid = strconv.Itoa(bid + i)
        petstr, _ := json.Marshal(pq)
        go DoCreate(string(petstr), client)
    }
}
```

Is problem about number of file handles or max connections?

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Comment: You may want to modify your concurrency such that you have a fixed set of goroutines that cooperate to finish an amount of work.  At the moment, you're fanning out a number of goroutines equal to the total amount of work, which might be a bit overkill.  See Worker Pools: https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools

Comment: i will test the Stability of my server . so i want to Analysis of  data when the server running  under high pressure.  the os is centos~~

Comment: i'm use the Web Framework is beego.  it's have problem~?

Comment: the error code is " Post http://xvz.myserver.com:9000/path/create: EOF "

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks to me that you might be having the issue described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23963271/1852838). Basically, the Go http client will try to reuse connections unless you've specifically indicated that it shouldn't either in the `Transport` you've set your `Client` instance to use or on the request itself with:

```
request.Close = true
```

This becomes a problem when the server on the other end closes the connection without indicating so with a `Connection: close` header in a response. The `net.http` code assumes that the connection is still open and so the next request that tries to use the connection next, encounters the `EOF` from the connection being closed the other time.

You would need to check what is happening on the connection around the 1000th request. Is the receiving server set to limit the number of connections per client? Is your code running into a connection timeout? In either case, if it so happens the connection is closed by the server in a way that the Go `Client` code can't predict, then you'll run into the `EOF`.

Answer (score 1):

- First, what for you instantiate new client each time `client := &http.Client{...` inside `DoCreate()` inside a loop? Client can be
  reusable even concurrently, so you can construct it more globally,
  say in `main()` seems to me.
- Then for me such error looks like
  produced by RoundTrip, so by connection, so possibly from server site. Can you
  test with mocking server?
- Finally if all that would not help, then
  yes, some systems have restriction on number of opened
  FileDescriptors which every `net.Conn` wants to have own. This
  restriction can be eliminated only on OS level.

Comment: thanks for your help, you're right, "Client can be reusable even concurrently"

Answer (score 1):

The EOF is usually from a server not returning a complete header (including both `CRLF`s), or the connection is closed before the header is complete. It's more likely that your overloading your server with concurrent requests, though you should still make sure you have adequate resources locally for the number of concurrent requests you're making. If `num` is large enough, you're going to run out of something.

Though the error isn't really descriptive, it's not anything to worry about more so than any other request error. It's an error condition, and handle it like you would any others. If you want to know for certain, you'll likely have to have a packet capture of the connection that cause the `EOF`.