# Golang HTTP request EOF

Tags: http, go, asynchronous, eof, goroutine

We are writing a proxy function that does async request to a service, which process some data. The data processing could take 0-10 seconds. After the requests get sent, depending on how long the service takes to process the data, we do the following:

If request gets a response back from service within 2 seconds: we forwards the response to whoever uses the proxy.
If request does not get a response back from service in 2 seconds: our proxy returns 202. Any further responses from our service are ignored.

Each request has its own threads. Below is our code:

```
func httpHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    defer r.Body.Close()


    // Forward-To is the host to forward the request to
    forwardTo := strings.TrimSpace(r.Header.Get("Forward-To"))

    // Is there no Forward-To header?
    if forwardTo == "" {
        // If so, return metrics.
        writeProxyMetrics(w, http.StatusOK, kafkaMsgId)
        return
    } 
    // Delete the Forward-To header for when we copy the request to proxy it
    r.Header.Del("Forward-To")

    // Read the body to copy it
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        atomic.AddInt64(&state.ActiveRequests, -1)
        writeProxyMetrics(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, kafkaMsgId)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    // Create the proxy request
    proxyRequest, err := http.NewRequest(r.Method, forwardTo, bytes.NewReader(body))
    if err != nil {
        atomic.AddInt64(&state.ActiveRequests, -1)
        writeProxyMetrics(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, kafkaMsgId)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    // Copy the headers
    proxyRequest.Header = r.Header

    // Do the actual request
    asyncRequests(w, proxyRequest)
}

func asyncRequests(w http.ResponseWriter, proxyRequest *http.Request) {
    timeoutChan := make(chan bool, 2)
    var requestResponse *http.Response
    var requestResponseBody []byte
    var requestError error

    go func() {
        // Do the request
        requestResponse, requestError = httpClient.Do(proxyRequest)
        // Was there no error?
        if requestError == nil {
            defer requestResponse.Body.Close()

            // Read the body
            if body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(requestResponse.Body); err == nil {
                requestResponseBody = body
            } else {
                fmt.Println("failed to read response body.")
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("[!] Request failed %v", requestError)
        }

        // We did not timeout, request finished
        timeoutChan <- false
    }()

    go func() {
        // Sleep for the timeout then notify the timeout channel
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(config.ProxyTimeout) * time.Millisecond)
        timeoutChan <- true
    }()

    if <-timeoutChan {
        //return 202 
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusAccepted)
    } else {
        //didn't time out and we got something back within 2 seconds
       if requestError == nil {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
       } else {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
       }
    }
}
```

Currently, we are experiencing a problem that if we send 2000 requests over 10 seconds, we are getting a lot of POST "URL" failed EOF errors. However, our service still actually gets the request. I've read a lot about this EOF error and it seems that it's related to subsequent requests trying to re-use the connections but connections dropped. 
I've read issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714494/golang-http-request-results-in-eof-errors-when-making-multiple-requests-successi/23963271#23963271)
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714494/golang-http-request-results-in-eof-errors-when-making-multiple-requests-successi/23963271#23963271)

I've stuck on this for almost a week and running out of ideas on how to further debug this. Could anyone please help take a look? Our go version is 1.13 and I also tried 1.14 and we are still experiencing this.

Comment: The proxyRequest gets passed in through asyncRequest function. asyncRequest function is called from httpHandler. I've edited the code to be more clear.

Comment: Hi @MuffinTop I think the proxyRequest is local to the httpHandler function. It is not a package level variable. My code pattern is exactly the same with the real code, except that I removed some unrelated and unnecessary variables such as logging and etc. proxyRequest is declared in httpHandler and passed into asyncRequest in our real code as well. Is it possible that the connection is closed once we hit time out and return 202? I know Content-Length and Keep-Alive headers could effect how Golang handles the connection. Maybe I should investigate into these headers.

Comment: Sorry, I found out I made a mistake when posting my question. The func asyncRequest should've been declared like this: `func asyncRequests(w http.ResponseWriter, proxyRequest *http.Request)` instead of `func asyncRequests(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)`. So I think proxyRequest is a local variable defined in httpHandler and was passed into asyncRequests. The only thing I could think of is to pass proxyRequest as a variable into the go routine that contains the Do().